# Toggle Actualizar base de datos Mysql automáticamente

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un sistema donde tendrás los siguientes campos de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para pasar la información, estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
<?php
....
$i = 0;
while($l = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
{
?>
<li>                    
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-on-danger custom-switch-off-success">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input toogle" id="onoff">
      <label for="onoff"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="Avisar[]" id="campo<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="onoff"><span class="text"><?php echo $l->NomeProduto; ?></span> </label>
      <div class="tools">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>                    
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  window.onload=function(){
  var onoff = document.getElementById('onoff');
  onoff.addEventListener('change', function() {
      estado = this.checked ? 'N' : 'S';
      var campo = document.getElementById("campo1").value = estado;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'alterar.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
             estado: this.checked,
             campo: campo
         },success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
          }
          }).done(function(msg) {
       });
  });
  }//]]>
  ///////////////////
  </script>
```

**alterar.php**

```
<?php
...
$id = $_POST["id"];
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$status = $_POST["campo"];
mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE campo
                             SET NomeProdutos = '',
                                 StatusProdutos = '".$status."'
                             WHERE IdProdutos = '';");
...
?>
```

El problema es que puedo obtener de solo 1 campo y no de varios dinámicamente. ¿Cómo paso los valores del nombre de los productos y la identificación y los guardo en la base de datos?

Comment: Utiliza arrays en el formulario, para que te llegue un campo con aquellos que se han cambiado. Mira el ejemplo de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array

Comment: Lo siento, Jakala. Mi español no es muy bueno. Mi problema estaría en Jquery. Pasar los valores a Jquery y rescatar en PHP.

Comment: si tu español  no es bueno claramente puedes buscar el sitio en portugues  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Hola Bryro. Participo en 3 idiomas. Inglés, portugués y español, pero he encontrado más respuestas aquí contigo. Uso Google Translate para facilitar nuestra comunicación, a pesar de tener conocimientos de español ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok todo sería más fácil si usaras algún `framework` de JS, pero si pretendes seguir usando PHP y JS vanilla puedes hacer lo siguiente.

En lugar de seleccionar el elemento con `getElementById` vas a seleccionar cada elemento de `checkbox` con `querySelectorAll('.clase')` donde clase sería una misma clase para todos esos elementos; esto te devuelve un `array` que puedes recorrer con `each` y que usarías para aplicar el `addEventListener`.

```javascript
const mychecks = document.querySelectorAll('.clase')

mychecks.forEach(mycheck => { 
    mycheck.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {
        estado = this.checked ? 'N' : 'S';
        var campo = this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'alterar.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                estado: this.checked,
                campo: campo
            },success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }).done(function(msg) {
        });

    })
})
```